# Sort the resulting DataFrame in pyspark using UDF

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am working in SPARK with **diamonds** dataframe. Data as below:

```
+-----+-------+-----+-------+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+
|carat|    cut|color|clarity|depth|table|price|   x|   y|   z|
+-----+-------+-----+-------+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+
| 0.23|  Ideal|    E|    SI2| 61.5| 55.0|  326|3.95|3.98|2.43|
| 0.21|Premium|    E|    SI1| 59.8| 61.0|  326|3.89|3.84|2.31|
| 0.23|   Good|    E|    VS1| 56.9| 65.0|  327|4.05|4.07|2.31|
| 0.29|Premium|    I|    VS2| 62.4| 58.0|  334| 4.2|4.23|2.63|
| 0.31|   Good|    J|    SI2| 63.3| 58.0|  335|4.34|4.35|2.75|
+-----+-------+-----+-------+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+
```

and schema:

```
root
|-- carat: double (nullable = true)
|-- cut: string (nullable = true)
|-- color: string (nullable = true)
|-- clarity: string (nullable = true)
|-- depth: double (nullable = true)
|-- table: double (nullable = true)
|-- price: integer (nullable = true)
|-- x: double (nullable = true)
|-- y: double (nullable = true)
```

I have created a custom function and registered as UDF:

```py
def rank_cut(cut):
    cut_class_dict = {"Fair": 1, "Good": 2, "Very Good": 3, "Premium": 4, "Ideal": 5}
    for cut, v in cut_class_dict():
        x['cut'] = v
 
    return v
```

```
spark.udf.register('rank_cut', rank_cut)
```

I want to use this custom function to sort my dataframe as below:

```
( 
diamonds
.groupBy('cut')
.agg(
    expr('COUNT(*) AS n_diamonds'),
    expr('ROUND(AVG(price)) AS avg_price'),
    expr('ROUND(AVG(carat),2) AS avg_carat'),
    expr('ROUND(AVG(depth),2) AS avg_depth'),
    expr('ROUND(AVG(table),2) AS avg_table'),
  
  
)
.rank_cut('cut')
.show()
)
```

but it is not working. Anything I am missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? You need to show us error messages (if any), and how your output (if present) is different from the output that you want.

Comment: Don't you think the UDF function `rank_cut` is correct?

Comment: Now that I look at it, there are several bugs in the definition of `rank_cut` alone, quite apart from anything having to do with Spark. This is why it's important to have a [**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

Comment: @jjramsey thx for hints. The message I receive is AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rank_cut'. Actually what I got is the code I already showed above. I need to sort the resulting dataframe from expr transformations in increasing order by quality of cut expressed in dictionary from 1-5

Comment: @SuyogShimpi i am not sure. Message of error I receive makes me think I am going wrong on this

Comment: Can you please give me some brief about `rank_cut`? What are the values for column `cut`?

Comment: @SuyogShimpi five levels for cut are, in increasing order of quality, Fair, Good, Very Good, Premium, and 
Ideal. The rank_cut() function should return the value 1 for an input of 'Fair', a value of 2 for an input 
of 'Good', 3 for an input of 'Very Good', 4 for an input of 'Premium', and 5 for an input of 'Ideal'.

Comment: The `AttributeError` indirectly indicates that you misunderstand what `spark.udf.register('rank_cut', rank_cut)` does. It does not automatically make `rank_cut` a method of PySpark dataframes.

Comment: @jjramsey any ideas how to solve?

Comment: I'll be blunt; it looks like you are missing a lot of background knowledge. I would seriously recommend a [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), because your `rank_cut` implementation doesn't make sense. As for PySpark itself, you should at least start by googling "spark.udf.register pyspark" (without the quotes), but you may also need to read through tutorials and books on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I changed my udf to :

```
cut_class_dict = {"Fair": 1, "Good": 2, "Very Good": 3, "Premium": 4, "Ideal": 5}
rank_cut =  udf(lambda cut: cut_class_dict.get(cut))
spark.udf.register('rank_cut', rank_cut)
```

and mapped it to cut column